# set delimiter when calling stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The quotes in strings being passed to sql for insertion into a table, are causing the stored proc to fail.  This seems to be common, and PHP users are told to escape the quotes.  If i understand this correctly, I'll have to escape the whole text, for sql storage, then unescape it for html display.  there must be a better way.  it occurred to me that setting the delimiter when calling the stored proc, might be a way.  or with php, redefining the quote symbol. so far, i haven't found anything on either of these ideas.

DEFINING THE DELIMITER IN SP CALL

```
call blog.postNewBlog(delimiter // begin {$blogText} end//, 'my text1', null, null, @out_dt, @out_title, @out_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

A different delimiter still doesn't save you from SQL injection: if someone knows what your delimiter is, they could manipulate your query to make it do bad things, simply by abusing the delimiter string within whatever text they submit.

The proper solution to this kind of issue is to use a database binding that uses *placeholders* in queries. For example, there are a bunch of database abstraction layers in PEAR that give you a syntax roughly like this:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO table VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4);
```

The great thing about this is that the abstraction layer will automatically take care of quotes (if necessary) and you don't have to care about them at all. (I'm fairly sure this will work for passing stuff to stored procedures, too, but I don't have specific experience with SPs and MySQL).

By the way, even with the standard kinds of approaches you don't need to *un*escape the values when getting them from the database: the escaping is only used within *queries*. Quotes are not stored in the database in escaped form, and in the same vein query results are not escaped either.